# Scala/Spark - Select one column from RDD(Array[String])

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My input data is `RDD[Array[String]]` type, the values are something like this:

```
["hello1", "world1", "test1", "Awww  that's bad."]
["hello2", "world2", "test2", "This is another test. I can't make it"]
["hello3", "world3", "test3", "no  it's not behaving at all. i'm mad."]
["hello4", "world4", "test4", "I need a  hug"]
```

I want the last column, so I did `inputdata.map(f => f(3))`. Strange enough, I am able to get output `RDD[String]` as expected for some of the rows, but for some, it's truncated.

Like this:

```
"Awww"
"This is another test. I can't make it"
"no"
"I need a  hug"
```

What happened to my 1st and 3rd row?

Edit:

To add on, I was printing the output using this:

```
output.take(4).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Can you show predicate function  `f`?

Comment: @AmitPrasad Huh? Sorry it's lambda express. ```f``` can be any letter...f(3) means taking element with index = 3 from the Array.

Comment: ahh, sorry my bad didn't see `RDD[Array[String]]` as your input type

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in your printing statement

Comment: `inputdata.map(f => f(3)).collect` or `output.take(4).foreach(println)`  both give expected output.

Comment: @AmitPrasad Thank you for the help. Didn't realise you removed your answer when I was about to accept it :) Anyway I figured it out. The issue was due to how I read the CSV. I fixed it and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: This should work as expected. The problem might stem from another part of your code. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem?

Comment: @xzk Glad it worked, I had not removed it. You can accept it if you feel. Thanks
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In the above example, you can you by using collect or even by printing it gives us the correct output.

Edit:

After adding a comma inside a `"`

[image]

Comment: I may have found the reason. Could you please try again by putting a ```,``` (comma) after "Awww"?

Comment: I am guessing the comma in my original data is causing the problem.